# Stop click event being triggered after timeout

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to move a div up and fade in another when on click, then if clicked again fade out the second div then move down the first div. This is working correctly though if I click quickly on the icon for doing this, the first div will move up then move down but the second div will still fade in. It doesn't do this when I remove the timeout for the div fading in.

```
$('#notes-icon').click(function(){ //brings up notes diaply & moves date/time to top
        $(this).toggleClass("pinned");
        if($('#notes-icon').hasClass('pinned')){
            $('#input-box').focus();
            $('#time-wrapper').css({top: "13%"})
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#notes-wrapper').css({opacity: 1});
            },400);
        }
        else {
            $('#notes-wrapper').css({opacity: 0});
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#time-wrapper').css({top: "50%"});
            },300);
        }
    })
```

html:

```
    <body id="background">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="icon-wrapper">
            <div id="notes-icon" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></div>
            <div id="bg-left" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></div>
            <div id="bg-right" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
            <div id="refresh" class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></div>
            <div id="pin" class="icons"><span></span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="time-wrapper">
            <div id="time"></div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="notes-wrapper" draggable="true">
                <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Create a reminder">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: post relevant html too

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My bad, added in the html too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clear timeout on every click

```
var timeoutID;
$('#notes-icon').click(function(){ 
     clearTimeout(timeoutID);
     ....
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j1cbw77c/)**

Comment: This fixed it! Thought it would be more, thanks for that!